# Metodo SQL NATIVO JPA

Tags: java, sql, jpa

tengo una query en nativa, y me devuelve una lista, la cosa es como puedo hacer para lo que me devuelve parsearlo en un DTO. Tengo esto alguna ayuda...

```js
@Query(value = 
   + "SELECT BLABLA, BLABLA2, BLABLA3, BLABLA4 
FROM BLABLATABLE ", nativeQuery = true)
 public List<BlablaDTO> getBlaBlaWithDades();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primero que nada dejemos un poco mas lindo ese método con su Query(entiendo que estas extendiendo para tu repository de jpaRepository) :

```
@Query(nativeQuery= true, value= "SELECT * FROM TABLA_DTO")
public List<ObjetoDto> getDTOsFromDB();
```

Ahora bien, primero que nada quisiera señalar el hecho de utilizar nativeQuery. Si estas utilizando el mapeo que nos brinda JPA deberías terminar de utilizarlo por completo. Esto conllevaría a que el método nos quede de la siguiente manera:

```
@Query("SELECT dto FROM ObjectoDto dto")
public List<ObjetoDto> getDTOsFromDB();
```

Lo que hicmos fué utilizar en la consulta, en este caso JPQL, la *entidad ObjetoDto (la cual esta mapeada con la tabla TABLA_DTO) para correspondernos con la utilizacion que JPA nos brinda.

Anteriormente asumimos que ObjectoDto era una entidad (por ende se corresponde con una tabla de nuestra base de datos). Ahora si vamos con el **problema planteado**. Si el DTO que usted quiere devolver de base de datos no se corresponde a ninguna tabla debería traer el objeto que si se encuentra mapeado y luego aplicarle un Adapter.

Entonces nuestro Repository nos quedaría igual :

```
@Query("SELECT dto FROM ObjectoDto dto")
public List<ObjetoDto> getDTOsFromDB();
```

Pero en nuestro Controller aplicaríamos, al momento de retornar nuestra ResponseEntity, un Adpater según que tipo de objeto nos gustaría devolver:

```
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(ObjetoDtoAdapter.apply(ObjetoDto));
```

Nuestro Adapter sería algo como :

```
@Component
public class ObjetoDtoAdapter implements Function<ObjetoDto, ObjetoDtoResponse> {

    @Override
    public ObjetoDtoResponse apply(ObjetoDto objetoDto) {
        return ObjetoDtoResponse.builder()
            .id(objetoDto.getId())
            .name(objetoDto.getName())
            .surname(objetoDto.getSurname())
            .build();
    }
}
```

Va a ser al momento de crear nuestro adapter en donde tendremos que "jugar" en que tipo de objeto queramos construir.

> *las entidades son clases que representa al modelo de datos, o mapea directamente contra una tabla de la base de datos